# Can quark-lepton mass be partially generated by Higgs?

Tags: mass, quarks, leptons

In the Standard Model, quark-lepton masses are also generated by their couplings with the Higgs particle as the W, Z vector bosons are. Their masses are different because the Yukawwa couplings are different.
In principles, quark-leptons can have non-zero masses before the Higgs mechanism. Higgs may add only corrections to the final masses.
Is there any way to determine that the quark-lepton masses are partially or totally generated by the Higgs mechanism?

Comment: See this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409313/higgs-couplings-and-fermion-masses/

Comment: I think you are misinformed: current quark masses are entirely generated by Higgs Yukawa couplings, and no mass of such is possible "before the Higgs mechanism". The strong interactions are only responsible for the generation of the bulk of constituent quark masses, and of course, hadrons, a subtle subject best left to itself. Your statement on lepton masses is then indefensible.

Comment: Higgs branching ratios or interparticle Higgs force could be measurably different from standard model expectations if such an extra mass contribution exists

Comment: Thank you Mitchell Porter for the good answer. I guess that we do not have the available observation data yet to confirm whether the extra mass exist. Even if you do, I think we have so many Yukawa coupling parameters and extra masses, we can fit with any measured ratios. Am I right?

Comment: No. Again, the only current-quark masses in the fundamental Lagrangian can *only* be due to the Yukawa couplings, if left-chiral SU(2) gauge invariance is not to be violated, and, with it, renormalizability, etc. This is a pretty unique structure: the second job of the Higgs, and, in the view of many, including myself, an equally important one compared to the first.

Comment: Dear Cosmas Zachos, We are not talking about the constituent quarks yet. We are talking about the current quark masses. In order to fit with observations, we can start from the zero quark masses and Yukawa coupling of quarks with Higgs. Then the quark mass is the  Yukawa coupling multiplied by Higgs'VEV.
                    $$  m_q = f_q v_0 $$
Alternatively, we can start from a non-zero quark mass $m_0$, so the quark mass will be
                    $$ m_q= m_0+ f_q v_0$$